# Maximize Entire Window Visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have an application designed in visual C# that is about a quarter of a normal computer screen. The reason its that small is because its easier to work with in Visual Studio. However, I would prefer if when I run it, it maximizes to the full screen. I tried this in my Main_Load:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

This causes the window itself to maximize, but the application itself is still quarter of the screen. Is there a way to maximize the application itself, and not just the window?

Comment: And we shall all sit here and imagine what you are seeing!

Comment: Also, is it WinForms? WPF?

Comment: And where's the difference between "window" and "application" in your case? Do you mean that the content of the window doesn't resize when the window is resized? In that case you'll have to implement docking/anchoring - please add tags on whether you use WinForms or WPF, as the way of achieving this differ between the two.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you have not docked or anchored any of the controls, meaning they will not move when the window is resized.

Have a look at docking here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock(v=vs.110).aspx

And have a look at anchoring controls here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx

Both pages should help you understand how to make controls resize with the window.

Answer (score 0):

Either you change the size of your application window in the visual studio designer so it fits your personal screen (bad idea), or you make your application aware of window size and window size changes and actively scale parts of the GUI programmatically (better).

Answer (score 0):

If WinForms, as others have stated, you need to [Anchor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx) and/or [Dock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock(v=vs.110).aspx) your controls so they know how to resize in relation to the Form when the Form size changes.  These will work for simple layouts.

**For more complicated needs**, however, check out the [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21wykkx(v=vs.110).aspx) and/or the [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9e8s203(v=vs.110).aspx).

A robust User Interface is probably going to be using **all** of these elements in one way or another...